# Android. Instantiating a interface?

Tags: android

I don't actually have a question, just want to ask you to explain me this code

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

...
```

}

is this about a class object which implements interface's method ?
even if it is, please explain it 
thanks

Comment: Feel free to delete this unless you know what you're doing with it. It's a callback, and it seems auto-generated when creating a fragment.

Comment: no man
take a look at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code creates interface `OnHeadlineSelectedListener` and requires that any activity to which the fragment is attached must implement this interface. `(OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity` tries to cast an activity to that interface, i.e. checks whether the activity implements it. If it does not, `ClassCastException` is thrown.

Comment: does that mean that onAttach is called by activity ? good answer. thank you

Comment: In fact, onAttach is called by Fragment Manager when an app tries to attach a fragment to an activity. Typical workflow: 1. App creates a fragment transaction (operation of attaching or detaching a fragment), 2. Fragment Manager executes the transaction asynchronously, 3. When needed, Fragment Manager calls onAttach and other callbacks. Step 1 is indeed usually placed in Activity, but it is not obligatory, it may be in any place in your app. Or even not in your code at all (when fragment is included in the activity layout).

Answer (score 0):

First, when you want to communicate between your activity and a fragment, for instance; if you have an application that lets users selected a headline and then open a details for it, you can use an interface as you show above.

**Interface definition**

An interface is a contract that whoever implements it must *respect/adhere to*. Just like any other contract in real life.

Now, in your Fragment, when you are ready to notify your activity of something - considering they implemented the interface for exactly this reason (to be notified), you ensure to cast the interface to your activity and throw a `ClassCastException` to let the class know that it must implement the interface.

**Type**

When you cast an interface to the activity, it implies that when an activity implements an interface, it becomes of that type (interface type).

**Subscriber/Publisher Design Pattern**

If you think about it, this sounds like the popular `Subscriber/Publisher` design pattern.

How?

The Fragment is the `publisher` in this case.

The activity is the `subscriber` here

So, in essence, in order to obey the rules of a contract, the activity MUST implement the interface that helps the two classes communicate!

I hope this helps.

By the way, this sounds and looks really similar to my demo application currently published on [PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simple.developer.fragments).